# How do i join a new node to conjure Open Stack Mitaka

Tags: juju, openstack, conjure-up

Now that I have the Mitaka version deployed using conjure, what would be the best method to add another compute node to this "one stop shop" deployment?

Answer (score 2):

conjure-up might let you go back into a running cloud and increase the number of machines allocated to a particular service.

But a better way is to start becoming familiar with the underlying Juju tools that conjure-up uses, because then you gain complete architectural flexibility. You can build any cloud you like, with any combination of services, spread across any number of machines.

conjure-up is basically a wizard that walks through a single "bundle of charms", but its relatively easy for you to make your own bundles and deploy them yourself. With Juju 2.0 and LXD you can learn that all on a laptop (with LXD as the "cloud" giving you "container machines"). If you have MAAS, then you bootstrap and deploy straight to bare metal.